# Cannot install dotnet-ef tool on Windows 11

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dotnet-tool

I'm trying to install the dotnet-ef tool via the dotnet-cli.

The command that I enter: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.4`

It gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\orbit>dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.4
C:\Users\orbit\AppData\Local\Temp\yfvm4duz.fcf\restore.csproj : error NU1211: Project restore must have a single package reference(s).
C:\Users\orbit\AppData\Local\Temp\yfvm4duz.fcf\restore.csproj : error NU1212: Invalid project-package combination for Packaging.Targets 0.1.171. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTool type
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

Some info using `dotnet --info` command:

```
C:\Users\orbit> dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.202
 Commit:    f8a55617d2

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22000
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.4
  Commit:  be98e88c76

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.303 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.407 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

I have an acces to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json so it's not the problem with my internet connection.

I tried to delete `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests` without any result.

Also I tried `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef --version 6.0.4 --ignore-failed-sources` command. The same exception message.

I found that this problem could be not only with the dontet-ef tool, but with every tool, because I tried to install `dotnetsay` tool and got the same exact error messages.

Comment: Could you try to install .net 3.1 SDK https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1 before execute your command?

Comment: I installed .net 3.1 SDK, reload the console, and nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

Try to uninstall it with this command:

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef
```

then install (without --version) like this:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

and check the version, if you want to update to newer versions, try this command:

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

Comment: After executing the uninstall command I got this:
`A tool with the package Id 'dotnet-ef' could not be found.`
Without --version the command doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue by removing

- the executable `dotnet-ef.exe` from `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.dotnet\tools`
- the folder `dotnet-ef` from `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.dotnet\tools\.store\`

manually.

After that, I used `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.6`